# How to create round cornered Map View in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding rounded corners to a mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211731/adding-rounded-corners-to-a-mapview)

For my Android application i need to create a round cornered MapView, I surfed in Google i could found any solution. Please some body help to solve this problem if you knows this.

Thanks in Advance,

Rajapandian

Answer (score 3):

Just wrote a tutorial to have rounded corners on a MapView it's done programmatically so should scale well to all devices:

http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/rounded-corners-map-view-t56908.html

Once you have added the custom view class you can just instantiate a rounded mapview like so:

```
<com.blundell.tut.ui.widget.RoundedMapView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: yeah this one worked for me
http://blog.blundell-apps.com/rounded-corners-mapview/

Answer (score 0):

So I've achieved this affect by doing following: I've created a 9-patch drawable called round_corners and placed it in my drawable folder, then I use following xml to plot the map:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">/

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/center_map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:apiKey="your_key"
        />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corners"  
        ></LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use shape drawable use the following coding snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#ffffffff">
  </solid>
  <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dip" android:topRightRadius="10dip" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dip" android:bottomRightRadius="10dip">
  </corners>

</shape>
```

for more on shape drawables visit the link below.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

cheeers...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already tried this it does not worked out for me. The Map View overrides the curved edges.

Comment: place your mapview in any of the layout and then for that layout set drawable on background so actually layout(linear,relative,etc..) will be with rounded corners this might do the need.