# Rounded corners on a MapView without overlay

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to figure out what the most reasonable way to get a mapView to display rounded corners -

I've tried to override dispatchDraw/onDraw in both a frame and a class inheriting MapView with no success (just doesn't apply the effects I was expecting) - I'm assuming the mapView creates a layer similar to what the Camera classes do, and so doing things like overriding onDraw don't work as expected.

Every valid answer (like those at [Adding rounded corners to a mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211731/adding-rounded-corners-to-a-mapview)) that I've seen are all a variant of drawing corners on a mapView that happen to match the background. This won't work for me, since I'd like the whole object the MapView is a part of to be able to be dragged over other UI elements (in which case, you'll see the sharp corners of the overlay).

Is there another way I could do this? Seems like something with a PorterDuff mode should be possible, but without reasonable hooks into the drawing operations, I haven't figured out how to do it yet.