# How to set round corners MapView widget

Tags: android, android-mapview

How to set round corners MapView widget?

his is my MapView

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="260dp"
                app:liteMode="true"
                app:mapType="normal" />
```

thanks

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211731/adding-rounded-corners-to-a-mapview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding rounded corners to a mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211731/adding-rounded-corners-to-a-mapview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may try cardview as view parent

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:liteMode="true"
                app:mapType="normal" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: This solution cannot set radius to only one side.

Answer (score 2):

Ref : [Adding rounded corners to a mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211731/adding-rounded-corners-to-a-mapview)

> rectangle_rounded_corners.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="@color/color_gray5_eeeeee" />
    <corners android:radius="10px" />
</shape>
```

Using a linear layout and a margin of the same size of the drawable stroke width, like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/rectangle_rounded_corners"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_details_map_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```